# Basic parameters with `params` parameters. UI - router

Tags: angularjs, url, angular-ui-router, state, parameters

I've seen this in a codebase:

```
.state('product', {
    url: productPageUrl + '/:slug',
    params: {
      productId: null,
      color: null,
      size: null,
      product: null
    },
    ...
},
...
```

What does it mean?
All data after `/` will be slug, right?
But accessing $stateParams['productId'] returns correct id. ex: for url:

```
/product/product-name-homme-170758.html
```

return `170758` for `$stateParams['productId']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` defines non URL-route parameters. They just simply don't appear in the URL. In your case `slug` should be equal to `product-name-homme-170758.html`, and the `productId` is simply set with `ui-sref` or `$state.go`

In your example, it would be:

```
ui-sref="product({ slug: 'product-name-homme-170758.html', productId: 170758 })"
```

Comment: Thanks, So if I reload the state, I can't know what was the productId which came with that. Only thing I can do is extract it from the slug, I think. right?

Comment: While I haven't really used `params` before, I would say you're totally right.